# How to make iphone apps in two different languages?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, localization

Hey guys I was just wondering how to make apps in two different languages?
I think that I should create two files with all the variables in different languages each.
Is that right?

Comment: Changed "idiom" to "languages"

Comment: Can you change the question title as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What do you mean by "idiom"? Are you talking about internationalization and localization? If so, [start here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/InternatAndLocaliz.html). (Cocoa Touch has a fair amount of support for that built in.)

Comment: My bet is "idioms" = "languages". So this is the correct answer.